# How to trigger a 'change' event with parameters?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

This is the first time I use the trigger method with maybe needed parameters and it doesn't work.

I use it with method without parameter and no issue :(

I don't understand the options I need to pass to the trigger method: https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/trigger.html

My component:

```
<template>
  ...
    <v-text-field
      :value="item.value"
      @change="closeEditMode(item.name, $event)"
      data-test-id="edit-field"
    />
  ...
</template>

<script>
  ...
    vmethods: {
      closeEditMode(itemNameToEdit, value) {
        if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
          this.$emit('itemChanged', {
            name: itemNameToEdit,
            value: value,
          });
          this.fieldToEdit = '';
        }
      },
    }
  ...
</script>
```

My test:

```
...
  it('does not render any text fields', async() => {
    ...
      let editableField = wrapper.find('[data-test-id="edit-field"]');
      editableField.element.value = 'abc';
      editableField.trigger('change'); //here
      await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
        
      editableField = wrapper.find('[data-test-id="edit-field"]');
      expect(editableField.exists()).toBeFalsy();
    });
  ...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the issue here is that you're listening for the Vuetify element's `change` event which hijacks the native change event and only emits the new value.

Since this is a custom event, you need to use `wrapper.vm.$emit()`

```js
let editableField = wrapper.find('[data-test-id="edit-field"]');

// emit the custom change event
editableField.vm.$emit('change', 'abc')
```